# mvc bootstrap tooltip closer to text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing an MVC Application with Bootstrap and I have a tooltip like this inside a `<tbody>`

```
 <td> <span data-trigger="manual" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"  title="View this participant">NAME </span></td>
```

What it shows is this

[image]

What I need is to show the tooltip closer to the bottom.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips appear right next to element
Make sure that element does not have paddings which are moving the tooltip away from text (maybe another span inside the span but without the padding)?

Or if there is another css rule moving the tooltip away, try to override it using some transformation?

Example:

```
    transform: translateY(10px);
```

Good luck!

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#overview

Comment: Thanks I checked and there is no padding... also I put transform: translateY(10px); and nothing happened..